# Sass "semantically" nesting tags and classes

Tags: css, html, sass

I am trying to enforce some kind of **semantic** css class nesting in Sass. I want to enforce that css code for sections can only be used in sections, to make sure that the `<section />` tag is used where it should semantically.

But I am running in troubles with the use of `&` in my Sass files. Consider the following html:

```html
<section class="section-home">
  <h1 class="section-home__heading">Section heading</h1>
  <p class="section-home__intro">This is some random text</p>
</section>
```

I would assume I could use the following code in Sass, but no:

```sass
section {
  &.section-home {
    background-color: white;
    &__heading {
      font-size: 5rem;
    }
    &__intro {
      color: grey;
    } 
  }  
}
```

Sass renders it into the following CSS:

```css
section.section-home{background-color:#fff}
section.section-home__heading{font-size:5rem}
section.section-home__intro{color:grey}
```

And that is not what I expect or need, I want:

```css
section.section-home{background-color:#fff} 
section.section-home .section-home__heading{font-size:5rem} 
section.section-home .section-home__intro{color:grey}
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: No, it's not a bug; that's what you should have expected. Why would the inner and outer uses of `&` behave differently?

Comment: Yeah, OK. But how to make use of the `&`? That's the point of Sass while using BEM isn't it?

Comment: I would like ```section.section-home{background-color:#fff}
section.section-home .section-home__heading{font-size:5rem}
section.section-home .section-home__intro{color:grey}```. See the html.

Comment: You need to add another layer of `.section-home`, as you have it twice in your expected output (e.g. `section.section-home .section-home__heading `).

Comment: You should probably not use `section` selector. After you drop it everything will be good with flat selectors. `.section-home { $__heading { ... $__icon { ... }}}`. https://jsfiddle.net/j5ecpj2o/

Comment: I would advise not using nesting at all, especially when using BEM. Mostly as it makes finding classes much harder. Trying to find the class 'section-home__heading' would be impossible if you split the class names up. you would have to search for __heading and that would appear in multiple places if your split class names up

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the CSS to:

```
section {
  &.section-home {
    background-color: white;

    .section-home {
      &__heading {
        font-size: 5rem;
      }
      &__intro {
        color: grey;
      } 
    }  
  }
}
```

This way Sass will interpret this as:

`section.section-home`

`section.section-home .section-home__heading`

`section.section-home .section-home__intro`

Comment: But that will not correctly create `section.section-home{background-color:#fff}`

Comment: Changed, could not properly interpret OP's needs before :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, but why call it ".section-" when you can simply call it ".home" when it already is restricted with the html tag.

```
section {
  &.section-home {
    background-color: white;

    .section-home__heading {
      font-size: 5rem;
    }

    .section-home__intro {
      color: grey;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't solve the issue, you didn't understand it. The idea is not to duplicate `section-home` part in all subbranches. That's why you need to use `&`.

Comment: Exactly done that, like in your example  ;-) but I can't use the `&`'s this way.

Comment: @AndrévanToly you can, just don't use root tag selector.

Comment: @dfsq you are right :) and I second that to not use the tag selector in the first place too.